# C# UNITY 2D trying to flip the sprite in the x direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

All I am trying to do is when the enemy turns around its sprite will flip, the code below is what I have managed but right now it only flips after two changes in direction which is close but not what I need. Please help.

```
   [HideInInspector]
    public bool facingRight = true;
    public float speed;
    Rigidbody2D rbody;
    public float timer;
    Animator anim;
    public float directionx;

// Use this for initialization

void Start()
    {
        rbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        StartCoroutine(Move(timer));
    }



    IEnumerator Move(float timer)
    {
        while (0 < 1)

        {
            Vector2 targetVelocity = new Vector2(directionx, 0);

            rbody.velocity = targetVelocity * speed;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);

            facingRight = !facingRight;

            Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;

            theScale.x *= -1;

            transform.localScale = theScale;

            Vector2 targetVelocity1 = new Vector2(-directionx, 0);

            rbody.velocity = targetVelocity1 * speed;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I know you already accepted an answer, but if you use a `SpriteRenderer` to render your sprite, why don't you just use the flipX property, shouldn't this do the trick? [SpriteRenderer.flipX](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-flipX.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is pretty self-explicative, you only need to set one variable to know the direction that the player starts to move (`m_FacingRight` in my case) and then decide when you want that the "flip" occurs calling `flipFunction()`:

```
private bool m_FacingRight = true;  // For determining which way the player is currently facing.  

private void flipFunction()
{
  // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
  m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

  // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
  Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
  theScale.x *= -1;
  transform.localScale = theScale;    
}
```